# disable link temporarily during quickflip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using on my site the plugin Quickflip with tabs on my [site](http://exerion.comule.com/prochaine.html) .

However if by exemple I click too fast on var2 and then var1 there is a bug.
That is why I am trying to put a timeout of 1s on each click of the tab so that it would wait for the flip to do.

Here is how I call the quickflip function (and tab)

```
  $('document').ready(function () {

        $('#flip-container').quickFlip();

        $('#flip-navigation li a').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                $('#flip-navigation li').each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                });
                $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
                var flipid = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
                $('#flip-container').quickFlipper({}, flipid, 1);

                return false;
            });
        });

    });
```

Is there a solution to this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to test your code and find out the problem that you mentioned.

[EDIT]

You want tabs can't be clicked until flip animation stop. I check the quickflip lib implementation and find out when div is flipping all the flip content display style will be set to "none". So I implement a "is animating" checking function.

Try this:

```
    $('#flip-navigation li a').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            $('#flip-navigation li').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            });
            $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
            var flipid = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);

            var isAnimating = true;
            $("#flip-container>div").each(function(index){
                if($(this).css("display")!=="none"&&index<3){
                    isAnimating=false;
                }
            });

            if(!isAnimating){
                $('#flip-container').quickFlipper({}, flipid, 1);
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
```

[EDIT]

And this is the updated answer [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G2bsE/4/)

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in your demo when I click on the tabs too fast, the bug is still here.

Comment: So you want tab link can't be clicked until previous flip animation stop?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be the most simple solution.

Comment: Thanks so much, the flip does not bug anymore. But do you know how to not change the color of the tab as well ?

Comment: Selected tab has class named selected which determine tab's color. Just remove all the logical about selected class and your tab will never change color.

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions that i know can solve your problem.
Have a look at [Callback](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp) which is used to make another function wait to the other function to finish first before performing, and you can put it together with [Unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function or [Event.Prevent](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Code may look something like this:

$('document').ready(function () {

```
    $('#flip-container').quickFlip();

    $('#flip-navigation li a').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            $('#flip-navigation li').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                $(this).$('#flip-navigation li a').unbind('click', handler);    //Mod 1
            });
            $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
            var flipid = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);

            //Mod 2 ---- Start
            $('#flip-container').quickFlipper({}, flipid, 1, function(){
                $(this).$('#flip-navigation li a').bind('click', handler);
            });
            //Mod 2 ---- End

            return false;
        });
    });

});
```

I am not entirely sure how to implement callback on the plugin, but [here](http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin) is a link to you that might be able to give you some idea how to implement callback on the quickflip plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check about it.